# Redis template no clear cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

The caching still after 24 seconds, I tried to set expire on each saves caching but I want to be generic in the configuration

```
   @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Object> jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = initJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
        RedisSerializer<String> stringSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
        template.setKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
        template.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.setDefaultSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
    
        template.expire(CacheType.EDITORIAL_CACHE.name(), 24, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        template.expire(CacheType.S3_CACHE.name(), 24, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
        return template;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your cache name is correct

Comment: @ch271828n yes I sure, I am using enums key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the javadoc, `expire` is `Set time to live for given key.`. In addition, your `@Bean public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(...)` will be called *when Spring application starts*, *only once*.

Thus, the code you write means, "when spring starts, expire that key. But I do not care about anything after spring starts." It is different from what you want to do - as you have mentioned "I tried to set expire on each saves caching".

If you need "set expire on each saves caching", what about changing your command when saving. Instead of using `SET` in redis, you should use `SETEX` (see https://redis.io/commands/setex). The counterpart in Spring is, for example, `void set(K key, V value, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ValueOperations.html).

Comment: yeah, I don't want to save the key each time I update the product, I want to set it as the default value, and each key has a default value because I am using hash redis key

Comment: @yali There is no default value in spring data redis or redis itself. However, you can *wrap* your redistemplate into what you want. For example, you can let every call to redis use your `MyRedisTemplate`, and you write some set-the-timeout logic in it.

Comment: Hmmm so example: 'redisTemplate.expire(key, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS);' each time I will save product it will resave the cache expired time 
  right ? or Redis will look into Redis key if has expired time and it will ignore it ?

Comment: @yali when you call that `expire` method, you are setting it to be expired 24 hours from now.

Comment: There are also other ways. For example, if you want it to be expired at this midnight, you can use another overload of the expire method. For even more fine grained control, you can firstly fetch the current TTL and then do whatever you like.

Comment: great, you are a right and more fine-grained control, do u have an example or link for you  use another overload of the expire method?

Comment: @yali It is called `expireAt`, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisKeyCommands.html and https://redis.io/commands/expireat